# Reading Excel File in Django uploaded using html form

Tags: html, django, excel, python-3.x, web

I am learning django framework and trying to read an excel file

I want to upload file using html form(POST Method) and want to read in python for calculations so what should I do really confused  ?
Code Is Here 
form.html

```
<form method="POST" action="minmax_ans.html">{% csrf_tocken %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <p><b><h2>Upload File</h2></b><p>
   <input type="file" name="file" value="{{ source.title }}">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**I want to do some calculations using data in the file uploaded through html form if it is an excel file and display the result on result.html which I have not created yet because I cannot read the file**

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what isn't working for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
import pandas as pd
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    pd.read_excel(f, index_col=0)
```

Pandas read_excel accepts argument io in str, ExcelFile, xlrd.Book, path object or file-like object.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I would start by reading the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/

To read the excel file you can use `pandas`:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html